# Terraform Creating 2 Security groups

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am running a small terraform script to build a infra [Testing Purpose] and when I run the apply command, It created 2 different Security groups.

```
terraform { # Setting up with the provider as AWS
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 5.0"
    }
  }
}


provider "aws" {
  region                   = "ap-south-1"                         # Set your desired AWS region
  shared_config_files      = ["/home/terraform/.aws/config"]      # IAM user access key
  shared_credentials_files = ["/home/terraform/.aws/credentials"] # IAM user secret access key
}


resource "aws_vpc" "Terraform_VPC" {                              # Creating a new VPC and updating a CIDR block.
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"

  tags = {
    Name = "Terraform_VPC"
  }
}


# 4. Creating a Subnet                                             # Creating a Subnet using the above VPC and updating a CIDR block.

resource "aws_subnet" "Subnet_Terraform_VPC" {

  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.Terraform_VPC.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
  #availability_zone = "ap-south-1a"

  tags = {
    Name = "Subnet_Terraform_VPC"
  }
}

# 6. Create a Security Group to Allow posrts : 22, 80, 443         # Creating a Security group with the baic Inbound rules.

resource "aws_security_group" "Security_grp" {

  name        = "MySecurityGroup"
  description = "Allowing HTTP and HTTPS traffic rules only"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.Terraform_VPC.id
}
```

I do not want 2 different security groups to be created, so how can be avoid this or is the code or the script I have written needs to be altered.  Please help.

This is the outcome of the apply command, just in case if you want this to be reviewed.

```
aws_vpc_security_group_egress_rule.allow_all_traffic_ipv4: Refreshing state... [id=sgr-0bc100ed982b45496]
aws_vpc.Terraform_VPC: Refreshing state... [id=vpc-0dfc04fc2d8387e2f]
aws_security_group.Security_grp: Refreshing state... [id=sg-04ceaa545798c4fe3]
aws_subnet.Subnet_Terraform_VPC: Refreshing state... [id=subnet-0c3a158bca10e1565]

Note: Objects have changed outside of Terraform

Terraform detected the following changes made outside of Terraform since the last "terraform apply" which may have affected this plan:

  # aws_vpc.Terraform_VPC has been deleted
  - resource "aws_vpc" "Terraform_VPC" {
      - id                                   = "vpc-0dfc04fc2d8387e2f" -> null
        tags                                 = {
            "Name" = "Terraform_VPC"
        }
        # (15 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }


Unless you have made equivalent changes to your configuration, or ignored the relevant attributes using ignore_changes, the following plan may include actions to undo or respond to these
changes.

──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_security_group.Security_grp will be created
  + resource "aws_security_group" "Security_grp" {
      + arn                    = (known after apply)
      + description            = "Allowing HTTP and HTTPS traffic rules only"
      + egress                 = (known after apply)
      + id                     = (known after apply)
      + ingress                = (known after apply)
      + name                   = "MySecurityGroup"
      + name_prefix            = (known after apply)
      + owner_id               = (known after apply)
      + revoke_rules_on_delete = false
      + tags_all               = (known after apply)
      + vpc_id                 = (known after apply)
    }

  # aws_subnet.Subnet_Terraform_VPC will be created
  + resource "aws_subnet" "Subnet_Terraform_VPC" {
      + arn                                            = (known after apply)
      + assign_ipv6_address_on_creation                = false
      + availability_zone                              = (known after apply)
      + availability_zone_id                           = (known after apply)
      + cidr_block                                     = "10.0.0.0/24"
      + enable_dns64                                   = false
      + enable_resource_name_dns_a_record_on_launch    = false
      + enable_resource_name_dns_aaaa_record_on_launch = false
      + id                                             = (known after apply)
      + ipv6_cidr_block_association_id                 = (known after apply)
      + ipv6_native                                    = false
      + map_public_ip_on_launch                        = false
      + owner_id                                       = (known after apply)
      + private_dns_hostname_type_on_launch            = (known after apply)
      + tags                                           = {
          + "Name" = "Subnet_Terraform_VPC"
        }
      + tags_all                                       = {
          + "Name" = "Subnet_Terraform_VPC"
        }
      + vpc_id                                         = (known after apply)
    }

  # aws_vpc.Terraform_VPC will be created
  + resource "aws_vpc" "Terraform_VPC" {
      + arn                                  = (known after apply)
      + cidr_block                           = "10.0.0.0/16"
      + default_network_acl_id               = (known after apply)
      + default_route_table_id               = (known after apply)
      + default_security_group_id            = (known after apply)
      + dhcp_options_id                      = (known after apply)
      + enable_dns_hostnames                 = (known after apply)
      + enable_dns_support                   = true
      + enable_network_address_usage_metrics = (known after apply)
      + id                                   = (known after apply)
      + instance_tenancy                     = "default"
      + ipv6_association_id                  = (known after apply)
      + ipv6_cidr_block                      = (known after apply)
      + ipv6_cidr_block_network_border_group = (known after apply)
      + main_route_table_id                  = (known after apply)
      + owner_id                             = (known after apply)
      + tags                                 = {
          + "Name" = "Terraform_VPC"
        }
      + tags_all                             = {
          + "Name" = "Terraform_VPC"
        }
    }

Plan: 3 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Do you want to perform these actions?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.

  Enter a value: yes

aws_vpc.Terraform_VPC: Creating...
aws_vpc.Terraform_VPC: Creation complete after 1s [id=vpc-0d528d4b00fea8a9c]
aws_subnet.Subnet_Terraform_VPC: Creating...
aws_security_group.Security_grp: Creating...
aws_subnet.Subnet_Terraform_VPC: Creation complete after 1s [id=subnet-07d89893b462c9448]
aws_security_group.Security_grp: Creation complete after 2s [id=sg-019cfcfa02dd2d1ab]

Apply complete! Resources: 3 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

Comment: Actually, the output shows only one security group being created. Are there any errors? Because based on the output it seems there aren't any.

Comment: Yes, sorry I have now destroyed it, but was able to capture a small pic of it. If you see these both has the same VPC_ID

https://prnt.sc/GWgc8kbjl-5J

Comment: Sorry. forgot to update that there is no error generated.

Comment: The screenshot shows nothing except that the same SG is used in two places.

Comment: Are you running this terraform code locally or in a pipeline? ... my concern is the state ... nothing in your code points to something been "bad" there, so I'm looking for something external that you might not accounted for

Comment: Hi Helder, I am running this locally to create this AWS services.

Currently, if you see that there is only this single default security group

https://prnt.sc/CBgYBdh92W41

However, if run terraform apply, then apart from the above one, 2 more SG group gets created, instead of one single which I have defined it in the code

https://prnt.sc/9mfIVeG2SS06

So, don't want that other default SG to be created, and not sure why it is getting created or is this the default option.

Answer (score 1):

That second security group, with the name "default" is the default security group that comes with your VPC as documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/default-security-group.html). It was created when you created the new VPC.

Per the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76049613/terraform-vpc-and-default-security-group-issue), there isn't much you can do to prevent that from being created. You can however use the `aws_default_security_group` [resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/default_security_group) to remove all the rules from the default security group if you want to do that for security reasons.

Comment: Hi, I am running this locally to create this AWS services.

Currently, if you see that there is only this single default security group

https://prnt.sc/CBgYBdh92W41

However, if run terraform apply, then apart from the above one, 2 more SG group gets created, instead of one single which I have defined it in the code

https://prnt.sc/9mfIVeG2SS06

So, don't want that other default SG to be created, and not sure why it is getting created or is this the default option.

Comment: Please read my answer, I feel like I explained this very well. You get one `default` security group for each VPC you create. You can't stop that, but you can use Terraform to lock-down that security group. Your comment is just restating your original question.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I got what you mean and will lock-down that security group. Thanks.